# -m32 flag not working to build 32 bit application

Tags: c++, 32-bit, gcc-warning

I am trying to compile some super simple code in Code::Blocks using GCC 4.4. I am on OS X Mavericks if that matters. I'm trying to compile and make a 32 bit executable, so I've taken the advice of a bunch of stack overflow posts to add the -m32 flag to the compiler (in Code::Blocks, I did Project > Build Options > Compiler Settings > Other Options > added -m32).

The code is the standard hello world program that pops up in every main file. I'll post it here for those who aren't familiar with Code::Blocks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I go to build, I clean all the object files and rebuild, and I get the following warning which prevents an executable from being created:

```
||warning: ignoring file obj/Release/main.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): obj/Release/main.o|
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I thought the -m32 flag deals with these things.

Any ideas or directions I can take? If there's any info I left out let me know.

Comment: You should try this in terminal! Just write your code in some file and then cd to your code and compile it with flag options you need!

Comment: This is a link error. You need to add -m32 also to link options.

Comment: I added -m32 to the link options and I think it would compile if libstdc++ was built in 32 bit mode. Is there a way to to get libstdc++ in 32 bit? My mac came with OS X 10.9.4.